# BIOS menu to enable SSD as boot device

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, bios, dell-inspiron

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 15 3542, and trying to install Windows 7 on an SSD I've put in place of the DVD drive.
I could reach up to getting the SSD recognised in Disk Management of my existing Windows installation and also created a dedicated Disk and partition of that entire SSD drive.

Now when I try to install new Windows 7 on this SSD, I get the following error after selecting that drive as the target location:

"Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu."

Looking at this message, I first updated my BIOS to the latest version A14.
Then some help on Google search brought out that I need to change the SATA option to 'AHCI' from the boot menu.
To my surprise, AHCI is already selected and there is no other option to select.

Although the SSD is displayed as an 'ODD' in BIOS along with my regular hard disk as 'HDD', I cannot see any option to change the boot device from HDD to SSD, it only shows HDD, CD/DVD, USB Storage and network.

I'd be shortly uploading images of all my BIOS settings.

Comment: I'd note - as the main HDD, I've had no issues installing a SSD to machines as old as a c2d. I wonder if the problem is with the ODD bay/adaptor you are using.

Comment: Why _is_ it shown as "ODD"? SSDs do not imitate an optical disk drive regardless of which port you connect them to.

Comment: Could it be because I'm using a 'caddy' which holds the SSD and I've put it in place of DVD drive?
I followed this method after viewing lot of DIYs on YouTube.

Comment: I also suspected the 'caddy' adaptor, but since the SSD is successfully recongnised and usable inside my existing Windows 7 installation, I concluded the adaptor should be just fine.

Comment: UPDATE: Although I wasn't able to find a solution for this problem, I found a work around which serves the purpose for me. I put my SSD into original to HDD's slot and put the HDD into the 'caddy adaptor' and put it in the DVD drive slot. Was able install new Windows 7 on the SSD without any problem and could also booth from it Also, the original HDD can be accessed for data.